# How to unwrapped optional not unwrap showing --- accuracy: Optional("2.5")---

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to get data from dictionary and array into my custom struct it's saving but when I print it its value is given in optional(value).and it's not saving into the TableView cell with this problem :(

```
func findAllShops(){
    Alamofire.request(NEARBY_STORES, method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON{ (response) in

        if response.result.error == nil {

            do
            {
                guard let data = response.data else { return }
                if let json = try JSON(data: data).array {
                    for item in json {
                        let storeName = item["name"].stringValue
                        let storeCover = item["cover"].stringValue
                        let storeLogo = item["logo"].stringValue
                        let storeSpeed = item["delievery_time"].stringValue
                        let storeRating = item["average_rating"].stringValue
                        let minimumOrder = item["min_order_amt"].stringValue
                        let shopList = shopModel(shopName: storeName , shopBGImage: storeCover, shoplogo: storeLogo , speed: storeSpeed, accuracy: storeRating, minimumOrder: minimumOrder)
                        self.shopLists.append(shopList)
                    }
                    print(self.shopLists[1])
                }
            }
            catch let error as NSError {
                // error
                print("Error in the parsing")
                debugPrint(response.result.error as Any)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Expected Output-->**

> shopModel(shopName: ("Madina Cash and Carry (F11)"), shopBGImage:
>   ("uploads/resturant_cover/resturant_4.jpg"), shopLogo:
>   ("uploads/resturants/resturant_4.jpg"), speed: ("24h"), accuracy:
>   ("2.5"), minimumOrder: ("1000"))

**Actual output -->**

> shopModel(shopName: Optional("Madina Cash and Carry (F11)"),
>   shopBGImage: Optional("uploads/resturant_cover/resturant_4.jpg"),
>   shopLogo: Optional("uploads/resturants/resturant_4.jpg"), speed:
>   Optional("24h"), accuracy: Optional("2.5"), minimumOrder:
>   Optional("1000"))

Answer (score 0):

You should rework `shopModel` struct/class so its vars will be non-optionals.

Or rewrite your code like here:

```
let storeName = item["name"] ?? "" // converts optionals to String
...
```

Answer (score 0):

**Approach: 1**

> Just assign `default` value when you will receive `nil` value from API.

**Code:**

```
  let storeName = item["name"].stringValue ?? ""
  let storeCover = item["cover"].stringValue ?? ""
  let storeLogo = item["logo"].stringValue ?? ""
  let storeSpeed = item["delievery_time"].stringValue ?? ""
  let storeRating = item["average_rating"].stringValue ?? ""
  let minimumOrder = item["min_order_amt"].stringValue ?? ""
```

**Approach: 2**

> When all values are mandatory from API then followed this approach.
>   If you have received `nil` value from API then
>   **application got crashed**.

**Code:**

```
  let storeName = item["name"].stringValue!
  let storeCover = item["cover"].stringValue!
  let storeLogo = item["logo"].stringValue!
  let storeSpeed = item["delievery_time"].stringValue!
  let storeRating = item["average_rating"].stringValue!
  let minimumOrder = item["min_order_amt"].stringValue!
```

Answer (score 0):

//TRY

```
    let storeName = String.init(format: "%@", item["name"] as! String)
    let storeCover = String.init(format: "%@", item["cover"] as! String)
    let storeLogo = String.init(format: "%@", item["logo"] as! String)
    let storeSpeed = String.init(format: "%@", item["delievery_time"] as! String)
    let storeRating = String.init(format: "%@", item["average_rating"] as! String)
    let minimumOrder =String.init(format: "%@", item["min_order_amt"] as! String)
```

OR

just Replace in your code

```
let shopList = shopModel(shopName: storeName! , shopBGImage: storeCover!, shoplogo: storeLogo! , speed: storeSpeed!, accuracy: storeRating!, minimumOrder: minimumOrder!)
```